# Unobvious array indexing

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

Recently I saw a lot of similiar code chunks in one project, which were written the following way:

```
String usedAlphabet = "x3w4tnu34urgbgierg";

byte c = // (something initialized earlier)

return usedAlphabet[(int)(c / 16)];
```

Now, what might be the reason to use the `(int)` cast while accessing the corresponding array?

*To me, it seems redundant, but I might be wrong or I may lack knowledge about the type casting mechanics.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, the cast is *redundant*. Does it aid in readability? Maybe, depending on the context. What could be done to *really* aid the readability of this "unobvious array indexing"? Good names I tell you (of course, the author should find the *right* names that communicate his intent, I've just made them up here):

```
int sectionSize = 16;

String usedAlphabet = "x3w4tnu34urgbgierg";
byte sectionIndex = // (something initialized earlier)

int alphabetIndex = sectionIndex / sectionSize;
return usedAlphabet[alphabetIndex]; // not so puzzling anymore
```

Answer (score 6):

You are right; it is redundant here. Sometimes a redundant cast can make the usage more *obvious to the reader*, but that would depend on the context.

Answer (score 5):

You are right - the division is integer division which will always result in an integer, so the cast is not needed.

However, `c` by itself lacks context (especially if it was not defined close to this usage), as it may no be obvious that this is a `byte / int`. It is possible that the cast was added as a readability aid.

Answer (score 2):

Since `c` is a `byte` and `16` is an `int`, the result of the division is an `int`, making the cast redundant. However it's possible that at one point the declaration of `c` was something like `long` or `double` and the cast was needed. When the declaration was changed the cast was never removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the cast from from a developer who is unclear on the rules of typing for the language, and so adopted a "better-safe-than-sorry" approach. I suspect most of us have done that at some point. That being said - the cast is unneeded and not even clarifying.